# Enable/disable a module that configure a provider

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I'm trying to conditionally create a module, which require some providers (`kubernetes`,`helm`,`kubectl`)
that are configured based on it outputs and I'm facing some issues.

for example, lets say I have a module (its name is `main`) which “calls” other modules, e.g `rds`, `eks_infra`, and `ecs` modules.

The main module is given some `enable`/`disable` flags, e.g `enable_rds`,`enable_eks` to conditionally enable its child modules

e.g

```
module "eks_infra" {
  count  = var.enable_eks ? 1 : 0
  ..
}
```

My issue is how should I configure the `kubernetes` provider if it’s dependant on the `eks_infra` module ?

sometimes `var.enable_eks` would be true → I want to have the `eks_infra` module.

And sometimes `var.enable_eks` would be false → I DON’T want to have the `eks_infra` module.

What I tried so far (which fails without any information) :

```
module "eks_infra" {
  source = "./modules/eks-infra"
  count  = var.enable_eks ? 1 : 0
 ..
}
```

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = var.enable_eks ? module.eks_infra.cluster_endpoint : ""
  cluster_ca_certificate = var.enable_eks ? base64decode(module.eks_infra.cluster_certificate_authority_data) : ""
  token                  = var.enable_eks ? module.eks_infra.cluster_auth_token : ""

  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "aws"   
    args = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks_infra.*.cluster_name, "--role-arn", "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE_NAME"]
  }
}
```

What would be the correct way of doing it ?

I saw [Enable/disable module with a providers](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/enable-disable-module-with-a-providers/16836) post and also [Providers Within Modules](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers) docs but can't find a good way of doing it